# Persist chrome tab after debugger close in VS Code

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I'm using VS Code debugger for chrome in attach mode. After I disconnect debugger current tab in chrome automatically close. Can chrome leave tab opened after debugger in VS Code closed? Chrome is launching with --remote-debugging-port=9222

Config in VS Code launch.json

```
{
      "name": "Attach to Chrome",
      "port": 9222,
      "request": "attach",
      "type": "chrome",
      "urlFilter": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/*",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/apps/client/src"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible (at least not at the time of this writing) with the builtin chrome launch config type. There's the [`cleanUp`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/main/OPTIONS.md#chrome-launch) option for that config type, but it only gives the option to close the tab or close the whole window after debugging finishes- not to leave it open.

There is functionality to allow extensions contributing debug configurations to contribute the functionality to disconnect from a debug session rather than terminate it (see [Debugger: Add option to allow disconnect and stop/terminate UI elements #116731](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116731)), but the extension has to implement support for that. I tried googling for existing feature requests by googling "`site://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues "feature-request" chrome debug "cleanUp" don't close`" and didn't find any in the top search results. I suggest that you [raise it as a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).